# powershell returning Get-ADComputer : The object name has bad syntax

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get all of the computers in a specific OU and ping them, but Im having trouble with Get-ADComputer.

code:

```
# Enter CSV file location
$csv = "filepath.csv"
# Add the target OU in the SearchBase parameter
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | Select Name | Sort-Object Name
$Computers = $Computers.Name
$Headers = "ComputerName,IP Address"
$Headers | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8
foreach ($computer in $Computers)
{
    Write-host "Pinging $Computer"
    $Test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Err
    if ($test -ne $null)
    {
        $IP = $Test.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
        $Output = "$Computer,$IP"
        $Output | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8 -Append
    }
    Else
    {
        $Output = "$Computer,$Err"
        $output | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8 -Append
    }
    cls
}
```

and im getting:

```
Get-ADComputer : The object name has bad syntax
At script.ps1:2 char 14
+ ... omputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers, ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    +CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    +FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft,ActiveDirectory,Management,Command.GetADComputer
```

ps. this code is taken from [here](https://smsagent.blog/2014/08/11/ping-all-the-computers-in-an-ad-ou/). yes I know Im not supposed to do that but after getting this error
time after time I wanted to try a code that works.

Comment: so ... can you run just that line on it's own?

Comment: no, it says the same thing.

Comment: so this line >>> `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | Select Name | Sort-Object Name` <<< fails? what happens if you run just the 1st part?

Comment: i tried running just ```Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com"``` and it also fails.

Comment: You're not using `"OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com"`. You're using something else, probably something that has spaces in the wrong spots. Look very closely.

Comment: I forgot to mention that not my actual OU path, I would prefer not to show it. but Im sure its correct because when I query for th ecomputers in my OU with ```dsquery computer``` it lists all of the computers under that OU successfully.

Comment: When you leave off the SearchBase parameter, does it work? If yes, then your OU path is incorrect, it's as simple as that. Maybe it contains special characters that need to be escaped - hard to say when you don't show it.

Comment: it turned out to be a spelling mistake, not in the OU name but even dumber. because my OU is under a lot of other OU's I must have gotten distracted while writing and messed up. my bad and thanks, you helped me find it

Comment: @PIGEXPERT - kool! glad to know that you found the error & the fix ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that the OU you're using as the search base is correct. This error occurs when it's off.

Apart from that, I recommend using [the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping). It's a lot faster than `Test-Connection` because you have more control over the ping timeout.

```
$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$pingTimeutMS = 200

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com" 

$results = $computers | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $ComputerName = $_.Name
    Write-Host "Pinging $ComputerName..."
    $test = $ping.Send($ComputerName, $pingTimeutMS)
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "Computer" = $ComputerName
        "IP Address" = if ($test.Status -eq "Success") { $test.Address } else { $test.Status }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv "filepath.csv" -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Not appending the lines to the CSV piecemeal feels a bit less clunky, too.

Comment: OU should be correct, ill try using ```System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping``` because you said its faster, and when i searched for this error a lot of people say it has something to do with the request taking too much time.

Comment: @PIGEXPERT It's not much faster in the success case (maybe a little bit when you send very many pings), but in the error case you don't need to wait as long as with `Test-Connection`.

Comment: I would prefer cutting time on successes rather then the fails, because the point of this script is to alert me when a computer is not connected.

Comment: @PIGEXPERT Think about that sentence again. What defines a ping success?

Comment: also, if youre still here, do you happen to know if its possible to use powershell to send an email? if it is then how? (we do have an email account for each user so maybe it can be accomplished with the active module too?)

Comment: I dont care about the actual ping in ms, just if its connected to the network. i would define that as a success

Comment: @PIGEXPERT ...but how do you know if a machine is connected to the network? You ping it, it responds. This takes two network trips (a.k.a. one round-trip) to wherever the machine is at. In the LAN maybe 10 ms - 5 each way. In slower networks it might take longer. Pinging a machine consists of waiting for a response. There is no way to accelerate the waiting, it takes as long as it takes. You can only decide giving up early when the response does not arrive within X ms. And for `Test-Connection` X is rather large. For `Ping.Send()` X is configurable.

Comment: For sending email there is `Send-MailMessage` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage))

Comment: the network is very fast, so Im fine with cutting it pretty short (10ms, maybe even less). also, if it helps you understand what im after, im actually talking about laptops here. I want to make sure that at the end of the day they are docked at their station. the connection to the domain is with an ethernet cable that is connected to the dock, so if they arent at their docking station they arent connected.

Comment: @PIGEXPERT *"if they arent at their docking station they arent connected"* - No, if they're not connected they are not connected. They could be connected via wireless LAN and respond to pings, "docked" is not a status in TCP/IP.

Comment: we dont have wireless. it is like i said, if they are not docked they are not connected.

Comment: @PIGEXPERT Since there is no way to accelerate the time you need to spend waiting for a reply, the only thing you can do to spend less time overall is to send multiple ping requests simultaneously. See https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/ccb7771ac7353a691a7fd65b71e2aa57 for a practical example in PowerShell. You might have to spend some time reading the .NET documentation explaining how asynchronous tasks work.

Comment: okay thanks, youve been really helpful. tyvm